# Prolog - Assign value instead of evaluating it

Tags: prolog

I'm fairly new to Prolog, so apologies if this is pretty simple, but it has had me stumped. Let's say I have:

```
setFlag(Value, Flag) :-
    Value =\= 1.
setFlag(Value, Flag) :-
    Value =:= 1,
    Flag is true.
```

Now, after getting these results I want to check if the Flag is/isn't 1. I feel like the best way to do that would be something like:

```
CheckFlag(UnrelatedInput1, UnlrelatedInput2) :-
    setFlag(Value, Flag),
    Flag =:= true.
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I say something like `Flag is true.` up above, Prolog is checking to see if Flag is actually true, (which it obviously isn't since I'm passing in 0 for the flag, because I don't want it to be inherently true). So, how do I ask Prolog to set Flag = true, on the top function so that I can check it below. Also, to me it almost seems like saying `Flag is true.` is the same as saying `Flag =:= true.` is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: 1. You can use [assert/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1). 2. You can pass the [state](https://www.metalevel.at/tist/) around. 3. You can create an actual [Prolog flag](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flag)

Comment: Are you trying to learn Prolog on your own without a book?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do it on my own.

Comment: So I could do something like assert(Flag(true)). instead of 'Flag is true'? @GuyCoder

Comment: You should at least get a [book](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/useful-prolog-references/1089#books). I do not know of anyone who has successfully taught themselves Prolog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the predefined predicate [`setarg/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setarg/3). For example:

```
?- Term = tuple(10,20,30), setarg(1, Term, 90).
Term = tuple(90, 20, 30).
```

Thus, a possible solution is to represent a flag as a term of the form `flag(Value)` and define `setFlag/2` as following:

```
setFlag(Flag, Value) :-
    setarg(1, Flag, Value).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- MyFlag = flag(10), setFlag(MyFlag,20).
MyFlag = flag(20).

?- MyFlag = flag(false), setFlag(MyFlag,true).
MyFlag = flag(true).

?- MyFlag = flag(true), setFlag(MyFlag,false).
MyFlag = flag(false).

?- MyFlag = flag(false), setFlag(MyFlag,true), MyFlag = flag(true).
MyFlag = flag(true).

?- MyFlag = flag(false), setFlag(MyFlag,true), MyFlag = flag(false).
false.
```